# What type of oil should I select for Greece?

Tags: oil-change

After talking to various mechanics each of who had a different opinion I confess that I am unable to understand what is the best oil for my car.

I live in Athens-Greece which means that we rarely have temperatures below 0 and we often have temperatures above 40 (Celcius).

My car is a Seat Altea XL (2010) , Turbo 1.8TSI which I purchased last year. When I took it to SEAT authorized service for the first check , they suggested Castrol Edge 5-30 but in less than 6.000km the car needed an oil refill.

Here you can see the manual page which has plenty of options to select from.

[image: Manual Page for Oil Properties]

Anyone can explain how to select the most suitable oil?

Comment: I just wanted to add that this engine has a bad reputation for being oil thirsty and a top-up after 6kkm is considered normal in the german car forums. I would use a slightly thicker oil, perhaps a 5w40 with VW 502 00 (I personally like Total Quartz 9000 Energy 5W40)

Comment: Reasons for my recommendation: 1. Your rather high ambient temperature 2. The high oil consumption for your car 3. Your manual allows it

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I expected and wanted to see answers like yours and that's the reason I posted a screenshot of the manual along with the common temperatures in Greece so that I would get more specific answers for my country.

Comment: Just for info, I use 10w40 year around in Toyota 3.4L V6 and temperatures vary from -20C in winter to 40C in summer. No issues at all. Though it calls for 5w30.

Answer (score 1):

> *they suggested Castrol Edge 5-30 but in less than 6.000km the car needed an oil refill.*

If they suggested 5w-30 it's likely because 5w-30 is what the mfg recommends, and therefore, is what you should use.

The oil needing to be refilled is not in any way related to your viscosity. You're either leaking or burning oil. If you're not seeing blue smoke out of the tail pipe, then you probably have a small leak from some seal or gasket. You'll need to inspect the engine to identify a leak location.

Comment: 5w-30 may be OK for Germany, but if you look at the manual screenshot or the image here:

[Oil Types](https://assets.blog.hemmings.com/wp-content/uploads//2014/04/viscosity_01_450.jpg)

5w-30 is not recommended for Greece where we rarely reach so low temperatures. Average temp in Athens is over 15 degrees celcius, not to mention summer which reaches 40+

Comment: It makes no difference. The engine runs at 100C. For "cold" starts at 15C or 40C, 5w will protect your engine just fine. The only time I would concern myself with non-mfg reccomended oil specs is something like starting a vehicle in Siberia where start-up temperatures are extremely *low*. Cold, thick oil could result in oil starvation on the first few cranks. In your case, your engine might as well just be "half-way warmed up".

Comment: I live in Siberia and last winter (the coldest it got was -35C) i used 5w-30 oil in my Honda CR-V without any issues. I had no trouble in summer either.